# How does Buddhism perceive swearing or vulgarities?

Tags: language

Swearing and the use of everyday vulgarity is often part of a conversation whether it be in jest or seriousness e.g. confrontation, frustration,etc

How is swearing or the use of vulgarities perceived in the context of Buddhism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you speak words which are (at the foundations) offensive to others, you are not practicing Right Speech very well. However, should you be around friends or alone, the words are just words.

> "One should speak only that word by which one would not torment
>   oneself nor harm others. That word is indeed well spoken.
>
> "One should speak only pleasant words, words which are acceptable (to
>   others). What one speaks without bringing evils to others is
>   pleasant."

— [Thag 21](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/thag/thag.21.00.irel.html#poem-05)

---

Here's a whole page [about 'Right Speech' on Access to Insight](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-vaca/index.html).